# Cannot link dll to mexfunction in Matlab cmex function

Tags: matlab, dll, mex

Does anyone have idea about how to link dll or lib in the Mex command?

I have a C code link a external function from GHXDLL.dll and GHXDLL.lib. I defined the external function in header that the same one i used to generate the dll and lib.

```
typedef struct GHX{
    double output[28];
    int val;
}GHX;
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {  // only need to export C interface if
    // used by C++ source code
#endif
#ifdef GHXDLL_EXPORTS
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
    MATHFUNCSDLL_API void GHXfunction(double *XIN, double *parameter, int mode, int hour, GHX *result);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I wrote a test code to call this function with linking to the lib and dll, and it works. Meanwhile, I wrote a simple test code for the Mex API, then I compile it from command line by

`mex test.c`,

and it works.

Then, I met problem. When I add the external function to the Mex API and compile in matlab with the following command, it fails.

```
mex -largeArrayDims -I'c:\Users\zzhang\API' -L'c:\Users\zzhang\API'  -lGHXDLL  GHXCmexAPI.c
```

The errors are:

```
Error using mex
   Creating library GHXCmexAPI.lib and object GHXCmexAPI.exp
GHXCmexAPI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GHXfunction referenced in function mexFunction
GHXCmexAPI.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I know this error means the mexfunction did not link to the lib with external function, but i have tried many different ways, and still cannot deal with it.

I hope someone can help me figure out how to mex it.

Thanks.

Zhicheng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List the DLL import library file by name rather than via `-l`.  Also add `-v` and inspect the `link.exe` command line:

```
mex -v -largeArrayDims -I'c:\Users\zzhang\API' -L'c:\Users\zzhang\API' ...
        GHXCmexAPI.c GHXDLL.lib
```

When inspecting the `link` command, also verify that there is a `/LIBPATH:` with the folder containing your DLL.

Comment: Thanks, i have fixed the problem.  The reason is that the Dll is built in a X32 platform, but the matlab R2014a require X64. SO i rebuild it in x64 platform, then it worked.